# Instantiate subclass without constructing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a subclass using the es6 class syntax. The subclass has some complicated logic to perform before calling the superclass constructor, so I tried factoring it out into a function. However, this seems to be impossible since `this` is not defined until after `super()` is called.

I've tried simply calling `super()` twice, once at the start of the constructor and once at the end, but it feels wrong and wastes the work that the superclass constructor does the first time.

```
class Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    console.log('some expensive thing with ' + x);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    let x = this.f();
    super(x);
  }

  f() {
    // complicated logic
    return 3;
  }
}

let c = new Child();
```

Running the code as written results in `ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor at new Child`. Removing `this` and attempting to call `f()` results in `ReferenceError: f is not defined at new Child`.

Is there any way to factor the subclass constructor logic somewhere else, even if it's okay if `this` isn't bound?

Comment: Why not just extract the complicated logic into a simple function and then just call it from `Parent.constructor` before do you other things inside of it? What you're trying to do is not possible, both constructors will get called in this case, and you can't do anything to prevent this from happening

Comment: You're trying to call an instance method before the instance exists. To work on the arguments only, you don't need an instance method, a static method or plain function will suffice.

Comment: @goto1 I'm actually subclassing a library class, so I don't have control over the parent. That said, subclassing twice and doing this in the first child makes it much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an initialization function separate from the constructor as that give you more control over when/if parent initialization happens.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    this.init(x);
    console.log("parent constructor does other stuff");
  }
  init(x) {
    console.log("parent init runs")
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    super(x);
  }

  init(x) {
    console.log("child init runs");
    super.init(x); // This call is optional if you don't want to run the parent's init code
  }
}

let c = new Child();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a static method could be a solution.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    console.log('some expensive thing with ' + x);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    let x = Child.f();
    super(x);
  }

  static f() {
    // complicated logic
    return 3;
  }
}

let c = new Child();
```

Comment: Maybe even use `new.target.f()` instead of `Child.f()`

Comment: @Bergi I have never used new.target before. From what I understand it just returns the Child object. What could be the benefit of this extra complication?

Comment: It would help if you would subclass `Child`, allowing you to overwrite the static method. `new GrandChild` would then call `GrandChild.f()` instead of `Child.f()`.